# Why was the Italian Presidency of the Council of Ministers likened to "a bus trip with the Marx brothers in the driver's seat"?

Tags: european-union, italy

[*The European Union: Politics and Policies* (2017 6 edn)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0813349842). [p. 126 Middle](https://books.google.com/books?id=4UdaDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT93&ots=FPFhEFW2kP&dq=%22labor%20flexibility%20and%20wage%20flexibility%20within%22&pg=PT138#v=onepage&q=%22marx%20brothers%22&f=false).

> [image]

1. What does "a bus trip with the Marx brothers in the driver's seat" mean?
2. *Why* was the Italian Presidency of the Council of Ministers likened to *"a bus trip with the Marx brothers in the driver's seat"*?

Comment: Are you aware of the comedians, Groucho Marx, Harpo Marx, Chico Marx and sometimes Zeppo Marx?

Comment: @JamesK No. Let me research them.

Comment: I don't think this is a politics question, more a matter of understanding an American cultural reference.

Comment: In more general terms it's probably a jab the controversies that Barroso was involved in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Manuel_Barroso#Controversies

Comment: Your book is talking about the rotating presidency of the Council, not of the Commission; please make this clear in your question. The events it refers to are the 2014-2015 rotations. Those are pretty obscure...

Comment: @JamesK the reference (first question) is one thing, how it relates to EU politics (second question) is on-topic here.

Comment: I don't see what the answer could be.  If you are familar with Marx Brothers movies, then the meaning is obvious.  "The Italian presidency was chaotic". That is the opinion of the author. I suspect that the OP, unfamiliar with the movies, thought that it had some connection to Karl Marx (a reasonable assumption in the context).  But feel free to write and answer if you feel you can.